# How to run a macro on multiple worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I want to run a macro on multiple worksheets. The sheets are named A,B,C...X,Y,Z. when I get to Z, then the sheets start of as AA,BB,CC...XX,YY,ZZ, then AAA,BBB,CCC...XXX,YYY,ZZZ and this repeats all the way to ZZZZZ. so there are 130 sheets that I need to run the macro on. I'm not even sure of where to start with this.

I have tried to come up with something to start with but I am new to VBE and don't even have a game plan on this. The worksheet names are in a lookup table called "lookupABC123". The macro that runs basically copies from "A" a range and then does some editing and moving rows to a master sheet. I got the macro to run on 7 sheets but in the future, it could go to 130 sheets.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simple answer is to put your macro in your PERSONAL MACRO WORKBOOK when you create it. This way, it is available not only for the current workbook, but for any new ones you create, no matter how many worksheets are in it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a *UDF()* to generate the sheet names and loop over the required sheets:

```
Public Function ConvertBase10(ByVal d As Double) As String
'
'  http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6604
'
    Dim S As String, tmp As Double, i As Integer, lastI As Integer
    Dim BaseSize As Integer
    Dim sNewBaseDigits As String
    sNewBaseDigits = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    BaseSize = Len(sNewBaseDigits)
    Do While Val(d) <> 0
        tmp = d
        i = 0
        Do While tmp >= BaseSize
            i = i + 1
            tmp = tmp / BaseSize
        Loop
        If i <> lastI - 1 And lastI <> 0 Then S = S & String(lastI - i - 1, Left(sNewBaseDigits, 1)) 'get the zero digits inside the number
        tmp = Int(tmp) 'truncate decimals
        S = S + Mid(sNewBaseDigits, tmp + 1, 1)
        d = d - tmp * (BaseSize ^ i)
        lastI = i
    Loop
    S = S & String(i, Left(sNewBaseDigits, 1)) 'get the zero digits at the end of the number
    ConvertBase10 = S
End Function


Sub MAIN()
   Dim SheetName As String

   For i = 1 To 130
      SheetName = ConvertBase10(i)
      MsgBox SheetName
      Sheets(SheetName).Activate
      '
      'process
      '
   Next i
End Sub
```

By the way, if you had 1,000,000 worksheets, you could only get to :

AWUTA

Comment: thanks gary's student. in the "sNewBaseDigits" how do i cycle through the worksheets. my sheets go from A..B.C.X.Y.Z, then AA,ZZ, then AAA,ZZZ all the way to AAAAA...ZZZZZ. nevermind, i see now what you are doing. but where do i put in my macro, is that in the main sub?

Comment: @DanM  **Have my** *MAIN* **macro call your macro.**